# how to get sub property of entity by name

Tags: c#

in class Person i have relation to class Position, and the class Position has a relation to class PositionTitle, and the PositionTitle has a property named Title

```
public class Person
{
   public Position Position{get;set;}
}

public class Position
{
   public PositionTitle PositionTitle{get;set;}
}

public class PositionTitle 
{
   public string Title{get;set;}
}
```

i have a string "Person.Position.PositionTitle.Title", how can i get this property of person with this string??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to split the string by dots, and then use reflection to get each property by name. You can get the *type* of the property using [`PropertyInfo.PropertyType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype.aspx) - then use that to fetch the next property in the chain. Something like this:

```
public object GetProperty(object source, string path)
{
    string[] bits = path.Split('.');
    Type type = source.GetType(); // Or pass this in
    object result = source;
    foreach (string bit in bits)
    {
        PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty(bit);
        type = prop.PropertyType;
        result = prop.GetValue(result, null);
    }
    return result;
}
```

You may well want to tweak this for binding flags etc, but it's the right basic idea.

Comment: It's probable that you'll want to handle nulls, either by throwing an exception (so you get a `NullReferenceException` rather than a cryptic `TargetException`) or returning `null` as soon as you get one.

Comment: @Gabe: Yes, quite possibly. I include that in "etc" :)

Comment: It was very usefull to me to catch the type of sub property.

Answer (score 1):

With using System.Reflection:

```
s = "Person.Position.PositionTitle.Title";

string[] split = s.Split(".");
int i = 0;

Type t = Type.GetType(split[0]);

object obj = null;

for (i=0; i < split.Count()-1; i++)
{
    PropertyInfo pi = t.getProperty(split[i+1]);
    pi.getValue(obj, null);
    t = pi.PropertyType();
}

result = (string)obj;
```